# What genre is SoulJourn 44?

Tags: identify-this-genre, genre-characteristics, alternative-rock

What genre is SoulJourn 44 (https://www.reverbnation.com/souljourn44)? I hear elements of power pop, alternative rock, punk, soul, folk and a lot of other stuff but I can't pin down the specific genre. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Souljourn 44 seems to label themselves as alternative (rock), which I think is the highest level genre classification that's worth thinking about.

[image: Souljourn 44 alternative self-classification]

[Alternative rock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_rock) itself as a classification is the incredibly broad classification that Souljourn 44 would fit under. Souljourn 44 is a project that clearly draws from many genres at once (the ones you listed are all fair); I would not say that there is one specific sub-genre that they would belong to.

If I were asked to describe Souljourn 44's music succinctly, I would simply say 'progressive alternative rock'. The progressive portion denoting how different their sound is from the norm

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was curious if there was any more specific genre since alternative is so broad. I guess there isn't one. Thanks for the input